# Clearing cache in Azure Function app and c#?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, clear-cache

I'm using Azure Functions App and c# for coding.
I want to clear the cache every 10 minutes for example, if there is a way to do that in the code ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if below references can give an idea.

[**Manage data expiration in a cache**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/caching#manage-data-expiration-in-a-cache)

> In most cases, data that's held in a cache is a copy of data that's
> held in the original data store. The data in the original data store
> might change after it was cached, causing the cached data to become
> stale. Many caching systems enable you to configure the cache to
> expire data and reduce the period for which data may be out of date.

**[MemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) class in C#**

This feature hasCache Eviction policies.
The values will be present in the memoryCache as long the Cache Eviction time is not expired.When expired ,the cache will be cleared  /removed and again application must get new values and start storing from original value i.e;populate the dictionary by checking the count.

---

You can set a default expiration policy when you configure the cache
i.e the Cache Eviction time .

***CacheItemPolicy can be used to add cache expiration time, change monitors, update callback etc***.Here is simple example of CachItemPolicy object, which Absolute Expiration duration.

**[Caching in Azure Functions](https://crmazurecomponents.wordpress.com/2018/08/11/caching-in-azure-functions/)**

```
public static class Function1
    {
   

 public static MemoryCache accessTokenCache = new MemoryCache("accessToken");
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
          //  accessTokenCache.Add("123", "123", new CacheItemPolicy() { Priority = CacheItemPriority.Default 
   
          ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;

          var cacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy { AbsoluteExpiration = 
          DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(60.0), }; 
         cache.Add("CacheName3", "Expires In A Minute", cacheItemPolicy);
       // We can remove any cache key-value object, using it's key and .Remove() method
         cache.Remove("CacheName");

});

            return new OkObjectResult("");
        }
    }
```

Another example that can be used in the function:

```
static MemoryCache memoryCacheTaxRates= new  MemoryCache("cachename");

if (memoryCachecachename.GetCount() == 0)
{
             RefreshCache(); //Get the values if nothing is in dictionary 
 
}

//other code

RefreshCache()
{
memoryCachecachename.Set("sourceKey", "targetKey", DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(Double.Parse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CacheEvictionTimeInMinutes"))));
}
```

You can check even by using `redis cache` but from the pricing perspective, it can cost more.

**References:**

1. [See In Memory cache C# (Explanation with example in .NET and .NET
   Core)](https://qawithexperts.com/article/c-sharp/in-memory-cache-c-explanation-with-example/302) and  [Stack Overflow reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66708402/unable-to-user-memory-cache-with-azure-function-app).
2. [Azure Functions and Caching: Sometimes its a tricky situation | by
   Raunak Narooka | Medium](https://raunaknarooka.medium.com/azure-functions-and-caching-sometimes-its-a-tricky-situation-985c7cceb1d5)
3. [Cleaning up Azure Durable Functions execution history - Joonas W's
   blog](https://joonasw.net/view/cleaning-up-azure-durable-functions-execution-history)

Answer (score 0):

You can use redis cache which will accept expiry date. Hope this will help.